# Не пойму что от меня хочетет mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL-запрос:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `yp038645_trash`.`Comments`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `yp038645_trash`.`Comments` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`Users_id` INT NOT NULL ,
`comment` TEXT( 500 ) NOT NULL ,
`date` TIMESTAMP( 12 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) ,
INDEX `fk_Comments_Users1_idx` ( `Users_id` ASC ) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Comments_Users1` FOREIGN KEY ( `Users_id` ) REFERENCES `yp038645_trash`.`Users` (
`id`
) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Ответ MySQL: Документация

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_Comments_Users1_idx` (`Users_' at line 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тип данных TIMESTAMP не имеет спецификации длины. [Мануал](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html).

Comment: А на локалке скрипт работал....

Comment: И что? не показатель - в зависимости от версии и настроек какие-то ляпы могут и игнорироваться...